# Synchronous Timer in .net?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm building an app in Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition, a Windows forms app, hence using Managed C++/CLI.

I'm new to this and need guidance on the following:

I have a function that basically reboots a HID interface device. I want to show a progress bar (kind of a dummy progress bar for about 30 seconds) that progresses every second to 30 counts. After this is over, I want the code after all this to execute.

I tried doing this with the System.Windows.Forms timer and it just executes the code right after the timer->Enabled = true event.

Here is some code if it helps:

```
   private:System::Void hidReboot(System::Void) {
    System::UInt16 res = 0;

    //bring up form to display progress bar

    res = SendRebootCmd();
    if (res == true)
    {
        timer1->Enabled = true; //in this tick event..i have the progress bar stuff
        //some other code here
    }
}
```

So basically, where the comment says //some other code here, I want to do that only when the progress bar is done and the timer has counted up to 30 ticks (1 second tick increments - 30 seconds).

I've tried putting a while loop there, but I can't use that as it hangs the UI thread, thus not raising the tick event of the timer.

Any suggestions, readings or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little unclear - You want the timer to tick 30 times, advancing the progress bar, then when its complete, run the reboot........ or do you want to display the bar, which does its own updating, then after 30 seconds of it, run the reboot... ?

Comment: If the duration of an operation is not known and you can't get a reasonable progress value I'd use some form of spinner or cyclic progress animation instead of a normal progress bar.

Comment: asawyer - I want run reboot, than right after I want to have the progress bar show up displaying the progress. When that is done, I want it to execute whatever the next line of code may be. The reboot takes about 20 seconds and only return from a successful reboot is a byte...so I am making an assumption and telling the user it takes about 30 seconds to reboot.

Comment: CodeInChaos - I will look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put any kind of wait into that function. Just start the timer and then exit the function.

Add the remainder of the function in the timer with a check that determines if the countdown has finished.

Comment: That might be a good way to go about it..what I am worried about is though that I will have to add various other timers...maybe 10 or so (there's erase commands, write commands, etc). Would this still be the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

`Windows.Forms.Timer` is appropriate for this.  I suspect your [Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval.aspx) is not appropriate.

In your case, set the Interval to 1000 (it's in ms, not seconds).  This should cause the Tick event to happen once per second.